# How to disable security filter for particular URL in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jax-rs

Hi I added rest web service for my project..When I call to the rest service without login to my account, my rest services redirect to login page... How can I remove this feature for only web service URL.... Other URLs need to this security....

This is my security configuration

```
package lk.slsi.security.configuration;

import lk.slsi.security.services.AuthenticationService;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;

/**
 * Created by ignotus on 1/26/2017.
 */
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    private RequestMatcher requestMatcher = new RequestMatcher() {

        private AntPathRequestMatcher[] disableCsrfMatcher = {
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("*/**")
        };

        @Override
        public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
            for (AntPathRequestMatcher match : disableCsrfMatcher) {
                if (match.matches(httpServletRequest)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/restservice/**");
        }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http    
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/view/public/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and().logout().invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .permitAll().logoutSuccessUrl("/");

        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        ShaPasswordEncoder encoder = new ShaPasswordEncoder(224);
        try {
            auth.userDetailsService(authenticationService).passwordEncoder(encoder);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error Occurred while authentication. [{}]", e);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my rest service config class(JAX-RS)

```
@ApplicationPath("TransferPermit/SlsitoCustoms/")
public class restConfig extends Application{

}
```

This is my rest service controller

```
@Path("getby")
public class webServiceforCustoms {

    @Autowired
    private permitServices permitServices;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of GenericResource
     */
    public webServiceforCustoms() {
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of lk.slsi.GenericResource
     *
     * @param id
     * @return an instance of java.lang.String
     */

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path("/date/{dtIssue}")
    public List<CustomsPermit> getXmlbyDate(@PathParam("dtIssue") String dtIssue) {
        List<CustomsPermit> permitRelease = permitServices.getPermitByDate(dtIssue);
        return permitRelease;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path("/id/{SNumber}")
    public CustomsPermit getXmlbyEntryNo(@PathParam("SNumber") String SNumber) {
        CustomsPermit permitRelease = permitServices.getPermitBySNumber(SNumber);
        return permitRelease;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path("/vatno/{importerVAT}")
    public List<CustomsPermit> getXmlbyVATNo(@PathParam("importerVAT") String importerVAT) {
        List<CustomsPermit> permitRelease = permitServices.getPermitByImporterVAT(importerVAT);
        return permitRelease;
    }

    /**
     * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of GenericResourcer
     *
     * @param content representation for the resource
     */
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public void putXml(String content) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make your code a [MCVE]. 1. `requestMatcher` is never used in your code.  2. Your REST controller seems to be under `/TransferPermit/SlsitoCustoms/getby`. Where do you configure path `/restservice`? 3. `try`and `catch`in your `configureGlobal` is not needed, this is not the place, where the authentication actually happens. It is just the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/restservice/**");
    }
```

Remove this from configure and add this

```
.antMatchers("/restservice/**"").permitAll()
```